# Is there any way to use google speech API (default free version) from android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, voice-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm trying to enable google speech API from the android widget. My idea is like if some click on a button from widget it will the API will start listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppWidgetProvider is just a BroadcastReceiver. Seems like google speech api need to bind to his service. But you can't bind to service from broadcast receiver. So the way is to use another service and `bindService` will work.

So just start your service (on button click from remoteViews) and make all your stuff with speech api here.

Comment: I didn't get your last line clearly, could you please clear me it?

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks for your great suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't answer that properly. Was busy. Nice to see that you figure out